# my "post" form doesn't post

Tags: php, ajax

I have a a problem when trying to send data from one page to another via using SESSION. 
In page 1 I have a form like:

```
<form id="myForm"  name="myForm" action="" method="post">

<input name="item_1">......</input> // an input for a number
<input name="comment1">......</input> // an input for text

</form>
```

to avoid refreshing, I use

```
function submitOnclick()
{
    $.post("thisPage.php", $("#myForm").serialize());
    redirectToAnotherPage();
}
```

then I tried to store data via using SESSION

```
function redirectToAnotherPage(){
    <?php $_SESSION['item_1']=$_POST['item_1'] ?>;
    <?php $_SESSION['comment1']=$_POST['comment1'] ?>;
    location.href='anotherPage.php';
}
```

but the $POST result is empty, I tried to replace $_POST['item_1'] with a number 1 and it did store the number to item_1, so I assume it is because  $_POST['item_1'] has some problems, I don't know why I can't get the form data in one page without submitting / refreshing,

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: i think you are redirecting and not submitting a form..

Comment: You can't post in to a javascript function...

Comment: Where is item_1? Your input name is item1. Isn't it?

Comment: You forgot `session_start();` at top of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can set a PHP session variable like that inside your javascript function. PHP is separate to javascript since PHP is serverside, those values will be read and assigned when the page first pre-processes.

There will be no change, whether the javascript function gets called or not.

Even without AJAX< just a simple PHP form will do. Please see below:

```
<form id="myForm"  name="myForm" action="anotherPage.php" method="post">

    <input name="item1">......</input>
    <input name="comment1">......</input>

</form>
```

To submit using javascript, just use something like this on your function:

```
function submitForm() {
    document.myform.submit();
}
```

Comment: Iam quite new to developing so not sure how thing work in detail, but I tried this and it does work:function redirectToAnotherPage(){
    <?php $_SESSION['item_1']=1 ?>;
    
}    so how can I use AJAX to make it work?

Comment: See if the above edit helps you, please see the action field and submit input element.

Comment: Thank you. I put the $_SESSION in the very beginning after  session_start() but still doesn't work, and can I use a <div> outside the <form> function as  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> ?

Comment: @HuangHao on anotherPage.php use $_POST instead of $_SESSION to get the values.

Comment: Hi , I used $_POST in anotherPage but it doesn't work BUT I tried to add <input type="submit" value="Submit"> and it works! But my problem is I need to have this submit button out of the form, Since in this page I used a <div> as a button to do the next and submitting, how can I make the <div> outside of the form works like <input type="submit" value="Submit"> ??

Comment: Hi, I did try document.myform.submit(); but the $_POST are still empty, meanwhile, <input type="submit" value="Submit"> is now the only way really making $_POST ...

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use a div to submit the form?

Comment: Just when I started laying things out it will be more easier...I am building a app look like survey page

Comment: You could use a <button type="submit"></button> tag inside the form and style it like you style the div. It would be the same as having an input type="submit" tag in the form. Using javascript to do things like submit a form is not the best practice anyway, because your users may disable javascript easily.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `name` of your input is not same with your `$_POST` index

your input: `<input name="item1">`

your post index: `$_POST['item_1']`

and also its not right way to use PHP function inside Js, this:

```
function redirectToAnotherPage(){
  <?php $_SESSION['item_1']=$_POST['item_1'] ?>;
  <?php $_SESSION['comment1']=$_POST['comment1'] ?>;
  location.href='anotherPage.php';
}
```

you need to set `$_SESSION` directly in `thisPage.php`(ajax post url)

**EDIT :**

dont use `serialize()`, this way instead:

```
function submitOnclick()
 {
   $.post(
     "thisPage.php",
     {item_1 : $('input[name="item_1"]').val(),
      comment1 : $('input[name="comment1"]').val()
      }
   );
   redirectToAnotherPage();
 }
```

good Luck !!!

Comment: Sorry I mistype here but it is correct in my file. I tried put the $_SESSION in the very beginning after session_start() but still doesn't work...